# When I tried to deploy rails files to EC2, An error occurred while installing pg is caused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, capistrano, amazon-rds

I'd like to deploy my rails project using Capistrano3.
Could you tell me how to deal withe the error? Thank you for your kindness.

When I tried to deploy, I got the following error message.

Deploy

```
cap production deploy
```

Erro code

```
bundle stdout: An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I typed like this,

```
   [ec2-user@ip-172-31-47-193 ~]$ gem install pg -v '0.18.2'
```

I got the following error.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150731-20195-11x65kw.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-pg
--without-pg
--enable-windows-cross
--disable-windows-cross
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0-static/pg-0.18.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: To use pg you need to have postgres dev package installed on the machine. Try installing the `postgresql93-devel`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by installing postgresql as following.Thx AOG!

```
sudo yum install postgresql93-server postgresql93-devel
```